# Refund to In App Purchase on Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an in app purchase that unlocks part of the app for a year. Its setup as Annual Subscription.

Temporarily running a promotion unlocking premium as one-time purchase.

One of the users emailed me and wanted to take advantage of the promotion. So I'm thinking Cancel / Refund his Subscription, and ask him to purchase again as one-time purchase.

My question is what happens after I cancel / refund his subscription order, does IAB still consider it a valid purchase or not ?

What happens when you queryInventory, is it no longer returned as his purchase or is it stilled returned and I have to handle the status somewhere in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it in your Google Wallet Merchant. Read [this Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/2741495?hl=en):

Once an order is refunded - on a non-rooted device - the order will be invalid if queried. IAB considers it as a `purchaseState==2` (2 is refunded according to Table 4 in [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html)). Note that the developer will be in charge to handle refunded items. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432382/android-in-app-billing-refund).

Comment: Thanks I know how to do it. My question is how IAB will handle the refund when you query for the SKU details ?

Comment: Once an order is refunded - on a non-rooted device - the order will be invalid if queried. IAB considers it as a refund and the developer will be in charge to handle refunded items. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432382/android-in-app-billing-refund

Comment: thanks that helps. Please update the answer so I can mark it complete. thanks.

Comment: I added some more details to the answer. Cheers.

Comment: So if I understand correctly after the refund, once I query the inventory canceled/refunded order will still be returned just with another status? Or are you saying that it wont be returned at all?

Comment: Even after a refund, it does return the purchase, but with the (purchaseStatus!=0). It is your responsibility as a developer to check the purchaseState and act accordingly. Also, please know that it takes almost an hour for Google servers to update the status of a purchase.

Comment: Much thanks for your reply and additional details added.